# Prevent socket leak of the Rails app with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, puma

Yesterday I switched to Puma in production. It uses the default configuration with 0-16 threads. In puma config file I don't close any connection explicitly, but I don't think it's necessary since I am not in cluster mode.

This morning the server is down and every second this error message gets written to the Puma error log:

```
LogStashLogger::Device::UDP - Errno::EMFILE - Too many open files - socket(2) - udp
```

I don't know if it is the gem itself, or the gem just cannot open the connection because another gem has exhausted the connections.

I don't even know how to debug such an error.
Any help is appreciated.

Or maybe is there any configuration of Puma that can make it fault tolerant to these kinds of errors?

UPDATE: here the [result of lsof](https://gist.github.com/collimarco/adcb2ec45d86c37a20560b942b3058bb)

Comment: Please check your ulimit on production.

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke the ulimit is 1024: I think the actual problem is a leak. However searching for ulimit I have also found lsof which can be useful

Comment: To investigate the issue further did you try [derailed_benchmarks](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks). This tool will actually help you in pointing out the issue. I guess it would be great if we have an exact reason for leak. Hope this helps